# Find conditions on a, b, c, and d for which the following system has solutions:

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find conditions on $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ for which the following system has solutions:

$$2x+4y+z+3w=a  $$
$$-3x+y+2z-2w=b  $$
$$12x+5y-4z+12w=c  $$
$$13x+10y-z+13w=d$$

I got the system down to:

Step 1: $$Eq4↔︎Eq1$$
$$Eq1→Eq1+2Eq2$$
$$Eq2→Eq2+3Eq3$$
$$Eq3→Eq3+4Eq2$$
$$13x+10y-z+13w=d$$
$$12y+5z+7w=b+3a$$
$$9y+4z+4w=c+4b$$
$$6y+5z-w=a+2b$$
Step 2: $$Eq4↔︎Eq2$$
$$Eq2→3Eq2-4Eq3$$
$$Eq3→4Eq3-3Eq2$$
$$13x+10y-z+13w=d$$
$$6y+5z-w+a+2b$$
$$z-5w=-9a+13b+4c$$
$$-z+5w=9a-13b-4c$$
Step 3: $$Eq4→Eq4+Eq3$$
$$13x+10y-z+13w = d  $$
$$6y+5z-w = a+2b  $$
$$z-5w =-9a+13b+4c $$ 
$$0=0$$

Would my answer be equation $3$?
There was an example in class where the last equation was (for example) $0=a+b+c$, and that was the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer doesn't help me. Telling me where I went wrong will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for where you went wrong: I think you tried to apply multiple row operations simultaneously (which results in an inequivalent system of equations).  However, row operations should be applied **one at a time**, and **order is important**.  Additionally, the choice of row operation should lead us closer to row echelon form.

Let's look at the proposed row operations for "step 1" performing one after the other:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ -3 & 1 & 2 & -2 & b \\ 12 & 5 & -4 & 12 & c \\ 13 & 10 & -1 & 13 & d \\ \end{bmatrix}
& \xrightarrow{R_1 \leftrightarrow R_4}
\begin{bmatrix} 13 & 10 & -1 & 13 & d \\ -3 & 1 & 2 & -2 & b \\ 12 & 5 & -4 & 12 & c \\ 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \xrightarrow{R_1 \gets R_1 + 2R_2}
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 12 & 3 & 9 & 2b+d \\ -3 & 1 & 2 & -2 & b \\ 12 & 5 & -4 & 12 & c \\ 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \xrightarrow{R_2 \gets R_2 + 3R_3}
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 12 & 3 & 9 & 2b+d \\ 33 & 16 & -10 & 34 & b+3c \\ 12 & 5 & -4 & 12 & c \\ 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \xrightarrow{R_3 \gets R_3 + 4R_2}
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 12 & 3 & 9 & 2b+d \\ 33 & 16 & -10 & 34 & b+3c \\ 144 & 69 & -44 & 148 & 4b+13c \\ 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

It looks nothing like what you seem to be aiming for (i.e., 0s in the right spots).

---

Here's what I get using Gaussian elimination:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ -3 & 1 & 2 & -2 & b \\ 12 & 5 & -4 & 12 & c \\ 13 & 10 & -1 & 13 & d \\ \end{bmatrix}
& \xrightarrow{R_2 \gets R_2+\tfrac{3}{2} R_1}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ 0 & 7 & \tfrac{7}{2} & \tfrac{5}{2} & \tfrac{3}{2}a+b \\ 12 & 5 & -4 & 12 & c \\ 13 & 10 & -1 & 13 & d \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \xrightarrow{R_3 \gets R_3-6 R_1}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ 0 & 7 & \tfrac{7}{2} & \tfrac{5}{2} & \tfrac{3}{2}a+b \\ 0 & -19 & -10 & -6 & -6a+c \\ 13 & 10 & -1 & 13 & d \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \xrightarrow{R_4 \gets R_4-\tfrac{13}{2} R_1}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ 0 & 7 & \tfrac{7}{2} & \tfrac{5}{2} & \tfrac{3}{2}a+b \\ 0 & -19 & -10 & -6 & -6a+c \\ 0 & -16 & -\tfrac{15}{2} & -\tfrac{13}{2} & -\tfrac{13}{2}a+d \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \xrightarrow{R_3 \gets R_3+\tfrac{19}{7} R_2}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ 0 & 7 & \tfrac{7}{2} & \tfrac{5}{2} & \tfrac{3}{2}a+b \\ 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{11}{14} & -\tfrac{27}{14}a+\tfrac{19}{7}b+c \\ 0 & -16 & -\tfrac{15}{2} & -\tfrac{13}{2} & -\tfrac{13}{2}a+d \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \xrightarrow{R_4 \gets R_4+\tfrac{16}{7} R_2}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ 0 & 7 & \tfrac{7}{2} & \tfrac{5}{2} & \tfrac{3}{2}a+b \\ 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{11}{14} & -\tfrac{27}{14}a+\tfrac{19}{7}b+c \\ 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & -\tfrac{11}{14} & -\tfrac{43}{14}a+\tfrac{16}{7}b+d \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \xrightarrow{R_4 \gets R_4+R_3}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\ 0 & 7 & \tfrac{7}{2} & \tfrac{5}{2} & \tfrac{3}{2}a+b \\ 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{11}{14} & -\tfrac{27}{14}a+\tfrac{19}{7}b+c \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5a+5b+c+d \\ \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
This is in row echelon form.  Thus, we conclude that this system of equations is consistent if and only if $-5a+5b+c+d=0$ (agreeing with Rene Schipperus's answer).  In fact, we can further say that there are infinitely many solutions whenever $-5a+5b+c+d=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep reducing to row echilon form, then if you have an equation of the form
$0=\text{combination of }a,b,c,d$ this will be your condition(s) if there are many such equations.

When I reduce it I get (with no guarantee I dint make a mistake, which is highly likely)

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&d-3a+2b\\
0&1&2&-2& -13a+7b +3d\\
0&0&-7&7&48a -18d-32b\\
0&0&0&0&d-5a+5b+c\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

So the condition is $d-5a+5b+c=0$ which is the same as in the comments.
You always must get some condition since the rank is the dimension of the image.

Comment: What I have got it down to is in echelon form.

Comment: Do you mean reduced row echelon form?

Comment: I think you must have made an error in your calculations

Comment: I have no idea how you got that.

Comment: I am trying to duplicate your answer. Which original equations are your final equations? For instance, did you keep them in the same order in your matrix?

Comment: No I think that I mixed them up. The best thing when reducing is to cease of $1$'s where they occur and use them.